# Line chart x axis starting point

Tags: c#, datetime, charts

I am trying to get my x-axes on this chart to begin on the day that the first data was added to the chart, so they do not just start in the middle of the chart. How can I do that

Also, the charts seems to end very suddenly ( no last gridline ) , is there a way to set that?

The problem is that

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = [any number];
```

won't really work since, the values are `DateTime` objects.

Hope someone can help

[Here](http://pastebin.com/kj348eZT) is the code - beginning from line 817

[image: Line charts centered]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the min/max axis values from DateTime to double using the DateTime ToOADate method:

```
DateTime min = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = min.ToOADate();
```

As for the right-most grid line, you can control that using the AxisY2 property of the ChartArea.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
```

This property will allow you to enable the secondary axis, control the labels, etc.